# PWA's browser cache not getting refreshed for re-generated scripts

Tags: vue.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

My current vue application was created using vue-cli and it uses the register-service-worker package by default. When I successfully build the app in production and deploy it on my server(which also has SSL certificate enabled), the pwa is generated as expected by the help of provided service worker, but when I make some changes to the app and deploy the new dist after rebuilding to the server, the browser cache is not being cleared. In short the service-worker is not detecting any changes to the new build. The cache is cleared when I force reload the browser. But this solution is not convenient on mobile devices and it is not a good experience for any user to force reload the app time to time just to get updates.

I even tried clearing cache on `updatefound` hook provided by service worker but I think the event itself is not firing or else the `updatefound` event would have cleared the cache on it's own.

My current registerServiceWorker script looks like this:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import { register } from 'register-service-worker';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready() {
      console.log(
        'App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n'
      );
    },
    registered() {
      console.log('Service worker has been registered.');
    },
    cached() {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.');
    },
    updatefound() {
      caches.keys().then((keys) => {
        keys.forEach(async (key) => { await caches.delete(key); });
      });
    },
    updated() {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
    },
    offline() {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.');
    },
    error(error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    },
  });
}
```

What should be done to clear the cache after a rebuild and deployment?

Comment: Are you using etags for your caching strategy?

Comment: @Remy No, I haven't.